# How to use system call Read? Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, linux, system, system-calls

I probably use my read function with a some kind of mistake but I can not recognize it.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

void exitProgram()
{
    syscall(SYS_write, 1, "norma", slen("norma"));
    syscall(SYS_exit, 1 , 0);
}

int main()
{
    func_desc arr[2];
    int choice;

    arr[0].name = "exit";
    arr[0].func = &exitProgram;

    syscall(SYS_write, 1, "Choose: ", slen("Choose: "));

    syscall(SYS_read, 0, choice, sizeof(choice));

    arr[choice-1].func();

    return 0;
}
```

If choice is '1' then it should call exitProgram() but instead it says Segmentation fault (core dumped). When I write a specific number then it works (example):

```
arr[0].func();
```

How can I fix this Segmentation fault (core dumped) problem?

Comment: Step 1: Check the return value of all system calls to make sure they succeed. Step 2: Check what's actually in `choice` before you use it.

Comment: Also, maybe try to get this code working with `fread`, `fwrite`, and `exit` before you start messing with syscalls.

Comment: Are you sure about those arguments for `read`?

Comment: Try `syscall(SYS_read, 0, (void*)&choice, sizeof(choice));`

Comment: @melpomene: That may be off-message, but at the very least the OP could use the glibc wrappers around the system calls...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>

void exitProgram()
{
    syscall(SYS_write, 1, "norma", strlen("norma"));
    syscall(SYS_exit, 1 , 0);
}

typedef struct func_desc {
    char const *name;
    void (*func)(void);
} func_desc;

int main()
{
    func_desc arr[2];
    char choice;

    arr[0].name = "exit";
    arr[0].func = &exitProgram;

    syscall(SYS_write, 1, "Choose: ", strlen("Choose: "));

    syscall(SYS_read, 0, &choice, sizeof(choice));

    arr[choice-'0'-1].func();

    return 0;
}
```

This works (only exactly if you enter the digit 1).

`read` takes the following arguments:

```
   ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

It'd probably be wise to use this glibc `read` wrapper (it would certainly prevent you from passing an int where a pointer is expected).